# How to write IsAuthorized function for authorizing role and its privileges in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my privilege collection which has privilege name and roles in it. say for example,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594264166fa2338250e000fc"),
    "name" : "ACCOUNT_ADD",
    "roles" : [ 
        "ADMINISTRATOR", 
        "MANAGER", 
        "CLERK"
    ],
    "status" : "ACTIVE"
}

I have to write a function called IsAuthorized() such that, When my control goes to adding an account, it should get the current user role and privilege name and check the same in the collection and returns true if that particular privilege name and role matches the collection otherwise it should not allow the user to add account. I have tried a function that is as follows,

```
 $rootScope.IsAuthorized = function (name, role) {
        privilegeServices.getPrivilegeList({"name": name}, {"roles": role}).then(function (results) {
            if (results.data._id) {
                var privilege = results.data;
                $location.path('/');
            }else {
                if (data.data.status == 'error') {
                    toaster.pop(data.data.status, "", data.data.message, 5000, 'trustedHtml');
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

```
angular.module('privileges',['datatables'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('privileges', {
                url: '/privileges',

                templateUrl: 'views/privileges.html',
                controller: 'privilegeController as controller',
                resolve: {
                    userRole: function () {
                        return 'ADMIN'
                    },
                    privileges: function (privilegeServices) {
                        return privilegeServices.getPrivilegeList({status: 'ACTIVE'});
                    },
                    privilege: function () {
                        return [];
                    }
                }
            }) 
    })
    .factory("privilegeServices", ['$http', function ($http, $scope) {

        var privilegeServices = {};
        privilegeServices.getPrivilegeList = function (privilegeSearch) {
            return $http.get("/api/privileges", {params: privilegeSearch}).then(function (results) {
                return results;
            });
        };

        privilegeServices.getPrivilege = function (id) {
            return $http.get("/api/privileges", {params: {_id: id}}).then(function (results) {
                return results;
            });
        };

        return privilegeServices;
    }]).controller('privilegeController', privilegeController);

function privilegeController($scope, $state,
                             $rootScope, privilegeServices, $location, privileges, privilege, $stateParams,
                             DTOptionsBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.privilegeId = $stateParams.privilegeId;
    $scope.privileges = privileges.data;
    $scope.privilege = privilege.data;
    $rootScope.title = "Privileges";
```

```
<th class="text-center">Add Account
                                <a ng-if="IsAuthorized();" ui-sref="account({accountId: ''})" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Add">
                                    <button name="ACCOUNT_ADD" id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></button>
                                </a>
                            </th>
```

In the html , once I click the add button, it triggers IsAuthorized() function. 
It has a callback in privilegeServices, after retriving role and name, simply check for the matching criteria and if exisits, allow the user to add account.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what if instead of invoking `IsAuthorized()` in the `ng-if`

```
<a ng-if="IsAuthorized();" ...
```

you make it a $rootScope property;

```
<a ng-if="IsAuthorized" ...
```

then, initialize it to `false` until the promise resolves

```
$rootScope.IsAuthorized = false;

function checkAuth(name, role) {
    privilegeServices.getPrivilegeList({"name": name}, {"roles": role}).then(function (results) {
        if (results.data._id) {
            var privilege = results.data;
            $rootScope.IsAuthorized = true;
            $location.path('/');
        }else {
            if (data.data.status == 'error') {
                toaster.pop(data.data.status, "", data.data.message, 5000, 'trustedHtml');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and somewhere else in your code

```
checkAuth("bob", "ADMIN");
```